Java 21 and Pentaho Data Integration
Hitachi has the worst documentation so I figured I would ask here.
Has anyone used Java 21 with Pentaho and had any issues?
I haven't had any issues running it, but wanted to see if there is anything I should look out for. In Java-11, I had memory issues.
I have not used Java-21 with Pentaho before and was simply asking a question if anyone had any experience with it.
Before you vote to close my question, this is not so much an opinion based question as I am just looking for someone who has had experience with it. If my question gets closed, I'll just go ask on the more user friendly Quora or Reddit, but I would prefer not to.
